# Non root docker permissions comes and goes

Tags: docker, ubuntu

In Ubuntu 19.04 I have installed docker:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.0-rc3
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        27fcb77
 Built:             Thu Jun 20 02:02:44 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
```

After installing docker I always run:

```
  sudo groupadd docker
  sudo gpasswd -a user docker
  newgrp docker
```

to make sure I can run docker without being root (and `user` is my actual username that I am logged in to ubuntu as).

But for some reason it only works sometimes. Half the times I get this error:

```
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Then I re-run:

```
 sudo gpasswd -a user docker
 newgrp docker
```

and it works again. I have tried to restart my terminal, reboot ubuntu but that does not make it consistent.

Any ideas to what goes on?

Comment: As mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user These two commands should add user to docker group permanently `sudo groupadd docker` `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

Comment: Also you need to logout and log-in back to make these commands in-effect.